# Doodle.com API / OAuth2Client with MVC4 & C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, oauth-2.0

im trying to implement a custom OAuth2Client for my ASP MVC4 Application so that the users can login with their doodle.com Account.

Based on [this Code,](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75424/Step-by-Step-Guide-to-Delicious-OAuth-API) i tried to give it a shot. Unfortunately, im always getting an error 400 "bad request". Any ideas on this? My Login-Urls look like this:

```
http://doodle.com/api1/oauth/requesttoken?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A49705%2FAccount%2FExternalLoginCallback%3F__provider__%3DDoodle%26__sid__%3D81daa197e305495b916b0f347fadf1c0&oauth_consumer_key=MYKEY&oauth_nonce=557897134&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1384429618&oauth_signature=NODC1gMPquzNx9TVg2wVoaZqjlk%3d
```

You can find my gist here: https://gist.github.com/davidroyal/7469100

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on my own. Backdraft: You have to authorize your application on every login. But for connecting your doodle.com account with an existing account in your application, its just perfect.

Please find the experimental implementation under:
https://gist.github.com/davidroyal/7469100